# how to access DB from command prompt to write SQL queries?

Tags: sql, oracle

how to connect to DB from command prompt in windows 7 for the purpose of writing  SQL queries and how to access all SQL  tables and files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Oracle [SQL*Plus](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_sqlplus.htm)

Which is an interactive and batch command-line query tool that is installed with Oracle Database Express Edition.

For MSSQL you may use the [sqlcmd Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For connect to SQL you can use [osql.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213090%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) tool, which allow you to connect to database, write queries, and even administering.